# Matching multiline strings doesm't work (regex, python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a multiline string, like this:

```
tt = """
some text
myvar=foo
some more text
"""
```

Now what i want to do is to extract the value behind 'myvar=', in this case 'foo'.

I tried like this:

```
import re
m = re.match('^myvar=(.*)$', tt, flags=re.MULTILINE)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

But `m`is always `None`. It only works with single line strings, like:

```
tt = 'myvar=foo'
```

What am I missing? I am new to python, but not to regex.

Comment: Use `re.search`. And you do not need `$`, remove it.

Comment: Wow thanks. That worked. Not very intuitive but ok.

Comment: Just read the docs very carefully: *The “`match`” operation succeeds only if the pattern matches at the start of the string **regardless of mode**, or at the starting position given by the optional pos argument regardless of whether a newline precedes it.*